# wrapping divs when overflow

Tags: html, css

I have two divs next to each other. The right div contains an image, and the left div contains text. I'm trying to figure out how to make the right div move below the image when it starts to cover the image, as the browser window is made smaller.

Below is the HTML and css. How should I adjust the css? Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
        <div class="divcontainer">

            <div class="leftdiv"><img src="images.jpg" alt="image"></div> 

            <div class="rightdiv">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Hic quoque suus est de summoque bono dissentiens dici vere 
            Peripateticus non potest. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. 
            Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Sed quanta sit 
            alias, nunc tantum pos
            </p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .divcontainer{  
        }

        .leftdiv{   
            float:left;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 1%;
            padding: 1%;        
        }

        .rightdiv{
            float:left;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 1%;
            padding: 1%;    
        }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your issue?

Comment: I'll try. It will take me some time, because it'll be my first time.

Comment: A fiddle is not required for this simple question. It's clear as it is now. However, if you like to learn for the future, have a look at the answers. They've created code snippets for you (similar to fiddle). It's easy, you click on the code snippet button and you get 4 boxes. One for HTML, another for CSS, another for JavaScript, and the last one to see the result. Welcome to SO and +1 for asking a well-formatted question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information.

Answer (score 2):

use flexbox for that:

```css
*,
*:before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body, p {
  margin: 0
}

.divcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: lightblue;
}

.divcontainer>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.leftdiv {
  flex: 0 20%
}

.rightdiv {
  flex: 0 70%
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divcontainer">
  <div class="leftdiv"><img src="//placehold.it/200x200" alt="image"></div>
  <div class="rightdiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hic quoque suus est de summoque bono dissentiens dici vere Peripateticus non potest. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Sed quanta sit alias, nunc
      tantum pos
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

if you want to have full `width` of those blocks in smaller screens, you can create a media query  something like:

```css
*,
*:before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
p {
  margin: 0
}

.divcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: lightblue;
}

.divcontainer>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.leftdiv {
  flex: 0 20%
}

.rightdiv {
  flex: 0 70%
}

img {
  display: block;
}

@media(max-width:640px) {
  .divcontainer>div {
    flex: 0 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divcontainer">
  <div class="leftdiv"><img src="//placehold.it/200x200" alt="image"></div>
  <div class="rightdiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hic quoque suus est de summoque bono dissentiens dici vere Peripateticus non potest. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Sed quanta sit alias, nunc
      tantum pos
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does that wrap the text box under the image box on small screens? I don't see that happening. That was the question, which you solution didn't answer. Well, unless you're suggesting to do it differently, in which case you need to explain that and why you think it's a better approach than the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't test this on a small screen, and I didn't use all of the code above. I'll do some testing and update.

Comment: @Sharon99 this works in smaller screens, but test it please. and test with the full code please

Comment: @Sharon99 I removed `max-width:100%` from `img`

Comment: Yes, of course it works perfectly. I didn't say otherwise. But works perfectly doesn't mean it answers the question perfectly. Like I said, you can simply explain why it is a better approach than wrapping the text under the image, that's all needed, a simple explanation.

Comment: Oh, now you removed `max-width:100%`, which means you acknowledged that I made a valid point. Now you're answer is perfect. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Use a media query to switch both elements to 100% width below a certain screen width (500px in my snippet):

(note that i also set up a rule for the image itself to fill its container width, except when that becomes wider than the original width - in my example 350px)

```css
  .divcontainer {
  padding: 10px;
}

.leftdiv {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
}

.leftdiv img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.rightdiv {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .leftdiv,
  .rightdiv {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="divcontainer">

  <div class="leftdiv"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x240" alt="image"></div>

  <div class="rightdiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hic quoque suus est de summoque bono dissentiens dici vere Peripateticus non potest. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Sed quanta sit alias, nunc
      tantum pos
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for code. It seems to work nicely. I'm just wondering what is the advantage of using this solution over the flex solution above?

Comment: flexbox can be a problem when it comes to older browsers, especially Internet Explorer before version 11. For version 10 you'd have to add prefix-rules, and on version 9 and before you'd have to build in a fallback solution. Since one possible fallback solution would forlook like my snippet, why not use that in the first place...

Comment: LOOL...oh boy who is going to support IE9 and IE10, we are already in I~E15

Comment: Well, believe it or not, there are customers of my clients who still use Windows XP and IE on that  -  and that's even IE8! It always depends on the customers - older people for example don't like to switch. Also people who need accessible websites often stick to their working system instead of upgrading to a configuration they can't be sure of...

Comment: @dippas ...and if you can support old browsers with a soution that isn't any more work and has no disadvantages in the particular situation, why not do it?

Comment: @Johannes everybody that uses windows are being automatically forced to update  to windows10 (unless you are not a regular user and know how to stop that), and with windows10 comes Edge already and iE11

Comment: I accept both arguments. I think for now I'll stick with this solution over the flex one, since I work with schools and it's possible that some of them are using old browsers. Still, using flex would probably be fine... Thanks to both of your for your help.

Comment: @dippas that's not correct. I still have Windows XP and Windows 7 systems for testing purposes, and I haven't been forced to update - I simply chose "no" once and that was it. And that's what some people did who I met, who simply don't want to switch

Comment: Note that I am using windows 7 on this computer, but I use chrome, and never touch explorer, unless I'm testing something.

Answer (score 1):

You specified them as 20% and 70% width. That means that they always fit in one line, because they will never cover 100% width. You have to use a [media-query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to specify a break-point where the CSS should change.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: That's a good explanation +1, but consider adding an example to enhance your answer. @dippas, no this is not a comment, it is a correct answer (one possible way of doing it), but it needs code example like I said.

Comment: Oops, Johannes was faster and posted the same answer but with full example.